# Jquery nav toogle class active doesn't work after link click

Tags: jquery, navigation

I have problem i hava navigation which has links with class="active" or inactive i wrote jquery script when you click link last active became inactive and clicked becames active the proble is when i click script works only for half second and page refreshes and links loses previous clases. The first link should always active after login because login redirects to him firstly

nav code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    var sidebar = $("#sidebar");
    sidebar.delegate("a.inactive", "click", function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      sidebar.find(".active").toggleClass("active inactive");
      $(this).toggleClass("active inactive");
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.active { background-color: yellow; }
.inactive { background-color: grey; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sidebar" class="nav-wrapper">
  <ul class="nav flex-column">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" href="{{ route('home') }}">
        <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
        <span>Darbuotojai</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link inactive" href="{{ url('/naujas') }}">
        <i class="material-icons">vertical_split</i>
        <span>Naujas darbuotojas</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link inactive" href="{{ url('/imones') }}">
        <i class="material-icons">note_add</i>
        <span>Įmonės</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link inactive" href="{{ url('/padaliniai') }}">
        <i class="material-icons">note_add</i>
        <span>Padaliniai</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Well i hope to find jquery solution, because i found only laravel solution in blade like this:

```
@if (\Request::is('home'))  
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="{{ route('home') }}">
          <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
          <span>Darbuotojai</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      @else
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link inactive" href="{{ route('home') }}">
          <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
          <span>Darbuotojai</span>
        </a>
      </li>
@endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[.delegate](https://api.jquery.com/delegate/) is deprecated

Instead use

```
sidebar.on("click","a.inactive", function (event) {
```

Also remove `$(document).ready(function() { })` - it is not needed

Add [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) handling to keep state

```js
$(function() {
  const $sidebar = $("#sidebar");
  $sidebar.on("click", "a.inactive", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // this statement will make the link NOT work
    $sidebar.find(".active").toggleClass("active inactive");
    $(this).toggleClass("active inactive");
  });
  $sidebar.on("click", "a.active", function(event) {
    // sessionStorage.setItem("active",$(this).index()); // does not work in a snippet  - uncomment on your page
  })
  const idx = 2; // sessionStorage.getItem("active") || 0; // uncomment and remove "2"
  $sidebar.find(".active").toggleClass("active inactive");
  $sidebar.find(".nav-link").eq(idx).toggleClass("active inactive");
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.inactive {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sidebar" class="nav-wrapper">
  <ul class="nav flex-column">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" href="{{ route('home') }}">
        <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
        <span>Darbuotojai</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link inactive" href="{{ url('/naujas') }}">
        <i class="material-icons">vertical_split</i>
        <span>Naujas darbuotojas</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link inactive" href="{{ url('/imones') }}">
        <i class="material-icons">note_add</i>
        <span>Įmonės</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link inactive" href="{{ url('/padaliniai') }}">
        <i class="material-icons">note_add</i>
        <span>Padaliniai</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Well it doesn't work. Now i have to click on link two times to make it work and when i active link the same situation navigation backs to his start. Maybe because i include navigation like partial.

Comment: Did you run my snippet? It seems to work as expected

Comment: Yes, try to click your links two times. It works only when you hit second time

Comment: I click on the right of each link and the color changes on first click

Comment: `event.preventDefault();` will stop the ink from working when it is inactive - not sure what you expected to happen - the link will ONLY work when it is active

Comment: yeah color changes, but link doesn't work. I need that link goes to the path where he is linked and class doesn't lost

Comment: That is not possible with the code you gave. If the link works, the page changes and the state of the links are lost unless you use sessionStorage

Comment: Interesting how to use that session storage?